# Backfill a list with preceding list items

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Say I have a list containing the values 1, 0 and -1. I am trying to find a method of creating a new list so that the preceding values determine the current values. So that for every zero that appears, if a positive number was the last seen in the list, it should become 1. Similarly, with negative numbers.

```
#Example:

x = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

so `x` would become

```
x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1,-1,-1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Anyone know of a decent way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Using a `for` loop seems pretty decent to me, you should give it a try. [ask]

Comment: @Julien.  If you can understand the question enough to propose a solution, what is the problem?

Comment: I understand the question. The problem is that you are supposed to show a minimum of research and effort before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple loop:

```
x = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]

out = []
prev = 1 # default value
for i in x:
    if i == 0:
        out.append(prev)
    else:
        out.append(i)
        prev = i
```

output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Slapping myself. Thanks for your time.